# I am getting different mean_absolute_error when i retrain my model everything same

Tags: keras, metric, error-handling, colab

[image]

I have set my numpy random seed to 0.
I am training on colab and using keras.
I didn't change anything.
I just re-ran my cell and the val_absolute_error changed.

#### Code:

```py
np.random.seed(0)
regressor = Sequential()
regressor.add(Dense(10, input_dim=1, activation='tanh'))
regressor.add(Dense(20, input_dim=1, activation='relu'))
regressor.add(Dense(15, input_dim=1, activation='tanh'))
regressor.add(Dense(1))
regressor.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_absolute_error', metrics=['mae'])
model = regressor.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=450, batch_size=10, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), verbose=1)

print(regressor.evaluate(X_test, y_test)) --> This is the error on the test set
```

**Please note that I made a mistake in the screenshot, it is the error in test set not val. set**

Comment: Do you set the random seed before splitting the data into training set and test set? If you use `train_test_split` from scikit-learn the split will be randomised.

Comment: May I add: the test/train split is different (pseudo random) if you dont fix the random state by using a seed. Also the model results are non-deterministic. For fully reproduceable results, alway choose a random state via setting a seed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this one too:

```
from tensorflow import set_random_seed
set_random_seed(123)
```

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the versions of the libraries you're using? I use `% pip freeze` to check.  Perhaps there is something inconsistent that causes this difference.  It looks like you've already got your seed set, so you're good there.

If it turns out to be a difference in the libraries, consider exporting the environment from one system and set your environment in the other to use those versions of your libraries.